# Diagonalization of $A=\begin{pmatrix}8&12&-18\\ 4&18&-20\\ 4&13&-15\end{pmatrix}$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$, how to find P, specifically, $P_2, P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, diagonalization

Using wolfram and symbolab, diagonalization of $\begin{pmatrix}8&12&-18\\ 4&18&-20\\ 4&13&-15\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow A=PDP^{-1}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}8&12&-18\\ 4&18&-20\\ 4&13&-15\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&3&2\\ 1&2&4\\ 1&2&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\ 0&4&0\\ 0&0&5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-2&-5&8\\ 1&1&-2\\ 0&1&-1\end{pmatrix}$

I'm struggling to derive the correct $P_2, P_3$, of $P= ({P_1, P_2 , P_3})$. I know the answer, but how do we get there?

---

Working for when $\lambda=4$ is:

$RREF \begin{pmatrix}8-4&12&-18\\ \:4&18-4&-20\\ \:\:4&13&-15-4\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1&0&-\frac{3}{2}\\ 0&1&-1\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-\frac{3}{2}\\ 0&1&-1\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ :

$v_1-\frac{3}{2}v_3=0 \rightarrow v_3=\frac{2}{3}v_1$

$v_2 - v_3=0\rightarrow v_3=v_2$

Thus, clearly: $\vec{v}= v_3\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{3}\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}: v_3$ is any constant  $\in \mathbb{R}$

Qn 1: Why is the answer $\begin{pmatrix}3\\\:2\\ \:2\end{pmatrix}$ instead?

---

Working for when $\lambda=5$ is:

$RREF \begin{pmatrix}8-5&12&-18\\ \:4&18-5&-20\\ \:\:4&13&-15-5\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1&0&-\frac{2}{3}\\ 0&1&-\frac{4}{3}\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-\frac{2}{3}\\ 0&1&-\frac{4}{3}\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ :

$v_1-\frac{2}{3}v_3=0 \rightarrow v_3=\frac{3}{2}v_1$

$v_2 -\frac{4}{3}v_3=0\rightarrow v_3=\frac{3}{4}v_2$

Thus, clearly: $\vec{v}= v_3\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{2}\\ \frac{4}{3}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}: v_3$ is any constant  $\in \mathbb{R}$

Even if I scaled it up by 3, $\vec{v}= v_3\cdot 3\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{2}\\ \frac{4}{3}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{9}{2}\\ 4\\ 3\end{pmatrix}$

Qn 2: Why is the answer $\begin{pmatrix}2\\\:4\\ \:3\end{pmatrix}$ instead?

Comment: I found the eigenvalues & eigenvectors of A by a direct calculation, but I don't like to post my answer. This forum expects you to do some work first.

Comment: @Dr.Sundar np I'll add more intricate working for $P_2$. Btw I already have the answer, what I need is an explanation for how $P_2$ is not $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{3}\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I posted an answer ; kindly check it out!

Comment: The first coefficient in your vector is wrong, $v_{3} = 2v_{1}/3 \implies v_{1} = 3 v_{3}/2$ not $2 v_{3}/ 3$.

Comment: @mattos, thanks but I think we have the same result? I just flipped it because I wanted to base it all in $v_3$, thus, for $\lambda=4: v_1-\frac{2}{3}v_3=0 \rightarrow v_1 = \frac{2}{3}v_3$, multiply both side by $\frac{3}{2}$,  $\rightarrow \frac{3}{2}v_1=v_3$?

Comment: Correction @mattos, you were correct we should see what $v_1$ equals, not what $v_3$ equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working for when $\lambda=2$ is:

RREF:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&-1\\ 
0&1&-1\\ 
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix} \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ :

$v_1- v_3=0 \rightarrow v_1= v_3$

$v_2 - v_3=0\rightarrow v_2=v_3$

Thus, clearly: $\vec{v}= v_3 \begin{pmatrix}
           1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}: v_3$ is any constant  $\in \mathbb{R}$

Taking $v_3 = 1$, we get
$$P_1 =  \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Working for when $\lambda=4$ is:

RREF:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-\frac{3}{2}\\ 0&1&-1\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ :

$v_1-\frac{3}{2}v_3=0 \rightarrow v_1=\frac{3}{2}v_3$

$v_2 - v_3=0\rightarrow v_2=v_3$

Thus, clearly: $\vec{v}= v_3\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{2}\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}: v_3$ is any constant  $\in \mathbb{R}$

Taking $v_3 = 2$, we get
$$P_2 =  \begin{pmatrix}3\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$

orking for when $\lambda=5$ is:

RREF:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-\frac{2}{3}\\ 0&1&-\frac{4}{3}\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ :

$v_1-\frac{2}{3}v_3=0 \rightarrow v_1=\frac{2}{3} v_3$

$v_2 - \frac{4}{3} v_3=0\rightarrow v_2= \frac{4}{3} v_3$

Thus, clearly: $\vec{v}= v_3
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{2}{3}\\
\frac{4}{3} \\ 
1\end{pmatrix}: v_3$ is any constant  $\in \mathbb{R}$

Taking $v_3 = 3$, we get
$$P_3 =  \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 4\\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Define
$$
P = \left[ \matrix{P_1 & P_2 & P_3 \cr} \right]
= \left[ \matrix{ 1 & 3 & 2 \cr
          1 & 2 & 4 \cr
            1 & 2 & 3 \cr} \right]
    $$

It is easy to verify that
$$
P^{-1} A P = D = \left[ \matrix{ 2 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 4 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 5 \cr} \right]
$$

Comment: I see, wow, I always thought we'd take the least value of $v_3$ so we can get a basis. I'm testing the same working for $P_3$ but that doesn't work either, would help me out? (I'll edit and include working for $P_3$ as well)

Comment: You may add in the question if you have question on $P_3$. This forum will help you if you start with mathematical calculations.

Comment: P3 for what eigenvalue? Can you reply?

Comment: Yes @Dr.Sundar, P3 for $\lambda =5$ please. I've also edited the question to add details as you've requested

Comment: I see, algebraically manipulated it the wrong way it seems and based it off $v_3$, whereas really I should see what exact values $v_1$ is

Comment: I fully worked out the problem. Calculations are right. I checked in MATLAB.

Comment: Amazing thank you, if you're happy to share the code, please send it across :) have a nice one

Comment: $[P, D]=eig(A)$ is the MATLAB command that gives you the matrix of eigenvectors P and the diagonal form D. Good luck!